# WooCommerce database relationship ERD - Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am doing a project for my uni and going to use WordPress and Woocommerce to build the eCommerce website. As we have to document all design there is also part of the database design. 
As I am not really designing it because woocommerce plug in does that for me then I wish to document it by showing ERD diagram and discuss that.

I have created ERD diagram by using MySQL WorkBench (reverse engineer) and everything is perfect apart that ERD diagram doesn't have any relationship between tables(no foreign keys). The engine of the database is InnoDB.

Am I missing something here or is this correct how it is designed that it's not using relationship please?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

**WooCommerce Relational Schema** 
This can be found in the /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-install.php file under get_schema() function.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have checked that and it looks like it is using foreign KEYs when creating tables but when I reverse ERD diagram tables has no relations... not sure if I understand this completely...